# Reload Ubuntu as at present it has stopped loading on startup

Tags: lenovo

Before leaving the States our company IT person installed Ubuntu on one of our Lenovo 500 laptops. This laptop had a new hard drive installed. All worked fine until arriving in the UK. Suddenly it would stop loading the OS so it is impossible to access the website. Our tech person just told me to buy a new laptop here. I am cheap and would like to fix this (I am writing on my other Asus, which doesn't have a CD/DVD drive like the Lenovo does).

Our IT person does not normally use an open source operating system like Ubuntu. Since the Ubuntu OS is on the Lenovo and something got corrupted, is it possible to roll back to an earlier point? There is nothing critical on this laptop.

Comment: So just install Ubuntu again. see this, http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

On the start of the boot process you ll see the grub screen for a few secs. Press the down arrow key and go the option rescue. From there you could try to salvage your installation or re-install grub in the root partition. You are not giving any info about your system i.e desktop, server, partitions...